# Action "Send iOS Debug build" failed: Error during processing: undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass

Tags: codenameone

Ref. [Build log](https://s3.amazonaws.com/codenameone-build-response/6fcb3ccb-e339-4bfa-a921-5b3e61c3a45d-1491581668315-error.txt)

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That error is a red herring.  The real issue is:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in [password redacted] -out cert.crt.pem -password pass:passwordHidden -passout pass:password
64991:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59.40.2/src/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1344:
64991:error:0D06C03A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_D2I_EX_PRIMITIVE:nested asn1 error:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59.40.2/src/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:848:
64991:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59.40.2/src/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:768:Field=version, Type=PKCS12
```

Most likely there is an issue with your certificate.  Probably a wrong password.  Or a problem with the certificate itself.